# How to store the decimal value of a Float Type in a variable (Swift)

Tags: swift

I have the beginnings of an app where one can input the amount of words in a speech they are going to give and it will figure out how long the speech will take based on talking speed. I would like the app to be able to store the only decimal values of the variable "sum" so I can then convert it into minutes and seconds. Here is the code for one of the buttons of the below and a snapshot of the UI, thank you in advance. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulta6.jpg

```
    @IBAction func slow(sender: UIButton) {
    let buttonPressed : Bool = true
    let a = (text1.text as NSString!).doubleValue
    let b : Int = 100
    let sum = Float(a) / Float(b)
    result.text = "\(sum) minutes"

    if sum >= 60 {
        let hour = Float(sum) / Float(60.0)
        let sum = "\(hour)"
        result.text = "\(sum) hours"

    }

    if buttonPressed {

        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `%` operator, which gives you the 'rest'. For example:

```
70 % 60.0 = 10
```

**EDIT:**

Not sure what you wanted to get by `doubleValue` on the string, but I am using characters count in my example:

```
@IBAction func slow(sender: UIButton) {
    let buttonPressed = true
    let a = text1.text!.characters.count
    let b = 100
    let sum = a / b
    result.text = "\(sum) minutes"

    if sum >= 60 {
        let h = sum / 60
        let m = sum % 60
        if m != 0 {
            result.text = "\(h) hours and \(m) minutes"
        } else {
            result.text = "\(h) hours"
        }
    } else {
        result.text = "\(sum) minutes"
    }

    if buttonPressed {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. However I am just a bit confused on how to apply this to my code for I am relatively new to programming. Would you mind giving me an example based off of the code I provided?

Comment: @JoeySmith I gave it a shot in my edit, not sure if this is what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBAction func slow(sender: UIButton) {
let buttonPressed = true
// stores input in var a as a double
var a = double(text1.text)! 
// defines constant b
let b = 100
// calculates sum
var sum = a / b
//calculates hours
var hours = sum / 60
//calculates minutes
var minutes = sum % 60

// if there are 1 or more hours and 1 or more minutes result displays
// hours and minutes
if hours > 0 && minutes != 0 {
    result.text = "\(hours) hours and \(minutes) minutes"
//if there are no minutes result just displays hours  
} else if minutes == 0{
    result.text = "\(hours) hours"
//if there are no hours result just displays minutes
} else if hours == 0 {
    result.text = "\(minutes) minutes"
}
```

You may also want to do some input validation to ensure the user does not enter letters which would bring the whole house down.